# How to implement debug logs in Android's JNI

Tags: android

I am trying to implement debug logs in the following file in the android code.

> > frameworks/base/services/jni/com_android_server_BatteryService.cpp

I have tried LOGE and __android_log_write(), however things doesn't work.
I have also tried to create a text file in the filesystem and then write it, however 
this also didnt work.

Comment: Typical mistake - most likely you've forgot to define LOG_TAG.

Comment: LOG_TAG is properly defined!....as #define LOG_TAG "BatteryService"

Comment: You removed your comment where you told that LOG_TAG actually was *not* defined.

Comment: actually I am new to JNI and I didn't see the LOG_TAG which was already defined....sorry for that

Comment: Thanks Andrej, I have fixed this issue. I have included my LOGE messages in the BatteryService after the JNINativeMethod table is registered. Any LOGE messages which are before registration is not working.

Answer (score 0):

```
#define LOG_TAG "BatteryService"
#include "utils/Log.h"

/* some code*/

LOGE("Mine logging is better than yours.");
```

Comment: In this case your problem is elsewhere.

Comment: You need to make sure that JNINativeMethod table is being registered from your service registration function. Have a look at `com_android_server_UsbService.cpp` for a reference.

Comment: Thanks Andrej, I have fixed this issue. I have included my LOGE messages in the BatteryService after the JNINativeMethod table is registered. Any LOGE messages which are before registration is not working.